How to remove `{{i:` and `}}` in string sides
I want to replace all occurrences of
{{i:very long text with some [special](https://google.com) nested text *here*}}

to
very long text with some [special](https://google.com) nested text *here*

That is, in pseudocode, I want to get <text> from {{i:<text>}} in a text file.
I don't mind which tool you use: grep, awk, ... This could be a beginning.

What problem are you having? Just replace all {{i: and }} with empty strings.

It should be a simple sed one-liner with two s/old/new/g commands.

@Barmar because I want to match {{i: to }} and I don't want to replace nested strings: {{i:hello {{i:hola}}}} would become hello {{i:hola}}

That's going to be really difficult, as regular expressions can't match balanced delimiters like this.

You need to write a recursive descent parser, not a simple command-line tool.

Could probably do it with a perl RE.

You can achieve the results you want using a recursive regex with Perl. This regex will match your strings, allowing for nested {{i:-}} pairs:
{{i:((?>(?:(?!{{i:|}}).)+|(?R))*)}}

It matches:

{{i: : literal {{i:
((?>(?:(?!{{i:|}}).)+|(?R))*) : zero or more (captured in group 1) of either

(?:(?!{{i:|}}).)+ : one or more of a character which is not at the start of a {{i: or }} sequence (this is a tempered greedy token); or
(?R) : recursion of the entire pattern


}} : literal }}

Regex demo on regex101
Assuming that test.txt contains:
{{i:very long text with {some} [special](https://google.com) nested text *here*}}
{{i:hello {{i:hola}}}}

Then you can:
perl -pe 's/{{i:((?>(?:(?!{{i:|}}).)+|(?R))*)}}/\1/' test.txt

Output:
very long text with {some} [special](https://google.com) nested text *here*
hello {{i:hola}}

If you want to remove all occurrences of {{i and }} you can just
perl -pe 's/{{i:|}}//g' test.txt


Great! You achieved my needs. Some comment here: how do you apply also in nested {{i: ...}}? So {{i:hello {{i:hola}}}} becomes hello hola?

@somenxavier I'm glad that worked for you. In terms of your other question, can't you just replace {{i: and }} with an empty string?

How to do that? What is the regex?

@somenxavier You could just perl -pe 's/{{i:|}}//' test.txt

It does not work: it produces hello {{i:hola}}}} not hello hola.

@somenxavier sorry, no access to linux here to test, I forgot the g flag: perl -pe 's/{{i:|}}//g' test.txt
